# bootstrap navbar dropdown menu hover color collapsed doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this CSS code

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #85E6FF;
    background-image: none;
}
```

When the window is maximized it works fine and my dropdown menus get the color #85E6FF when hovering. But when collapsed (on my cellphone for instance) there is no color change what so ever when hovering nor when I click. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show us more of the code you're using, as well as specifying whether this is Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 as the formatting for `dropdown-menu` is different between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a bootstrap style has a more specific selector than the one you're using for the mobile version.

When you have two or more CSS blocks whose selectors select the same element, and which both try to set the same property, then the block with the more specific selector wins out.

check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-selectors-specificity/

You can use an !important or you can use a more specific selector like:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #85E6FF;
    background-image: none;
}
```